# How to start searching of word after specific word in shell?

Tags: shell

> I've following text and I want to search **cat** after **hi**. It can be in very next line or 3rd-4th line? How to do using shell commands.

Hello
cat
dog
hi
dog
cat
cow
..
..

Answer (score 0):

```
nl a |grep -A 3 hi |sed '' |grep cat
```

-A 3 means pring 3 line, when found hi, then grep cat here, you can define 3 as you want